# When admin is logged in, admin-bar-rtl.min.css is not loaded on website view (the admin-bar is shown in the footer without CSS)

Tags: admin-bar, admin-css

When admin is logged in, the admin-bar on website view is shown in the footer without CSS.
I checked the source against other websites & it seems like admin-bar-rtl.min.css is not loaded on my case for some unknown reason.

---

UPDATE:
I discovered that setting DISALLOW_FILE_MODS to false fixes the issue, but I can't leave it that way because it's a production environment & I don't want admins to install stuff...

---

-- Any idea?

Comment: What's the Site Language set to in Settings -> General? And what's the User Language set to in your profile?

Comment: Both are set to Hebrew.